# Calculating the second-order correlation function for a 2-mode squeezed vacuum state

Tags: vacuum, quantum-optics, correlation-functions, quantum-states, squeezed-states

I am trying to calculate the second order correlation function $g^2(τ)$ at τ (delay) equal to zero, for a 2 modes squeezed vacuum state that is given by:

[image]

According to the following paper https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aba9186, if you consider the signal or idler photon individually, $g^2(τ)$ should be equal to 2 ideally meaning that you have a thermal state. Could you please explain that?

Answer (score 1):

The authors of the paper you reference measure the unheralded $g^{(2)}$ function, which means that they measure it for one mode (for example $a$) without conditioning these measurements on detection events in mode $b$. The local description of the state in mode $a$ is given by taking the partial trace over the mode $b$ in the state $|\psi_{sq}\rangle\langle\psi_{sq}|_{ab}$:

$$
\rho_a = \mathrm{tr}_b(|\psi_{sq}\rangle\langle\psi_{sq}|_{ab}).
$$

This is a straightforward calculation ([see this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/726075/spdc-one-arm-vs-very-weak-coherent-state/727891#727891)) that yields:

$$
\rho_a = (1-\lambda^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{2n} |n\rangle\langle n|_a,
$$

which is simply a thermal state.

The second-order autocorrelation function at zero delay is:

$$
g^{(2)}(0) = \frac{\langle \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{a} \rangle}{\langle \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a} \rangle^2}
$$

which using the commutation relation $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a} = \hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger} - 1$ can be re-written as:

$$
g^{(2)}(0) = \frac{\langle N^2 - N \rangle}{\langle N \rangle^2} =
1+\frac{\Delta N^2 - \langle N \rangle}{\langle N \rangle^2}, 
$$

where $N = \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$ is the photon number operator. For a thermal state the photon number variance is

$$
\Delta N^2 = \langle N \rangle^2 + \langle N \rangle
$$

(I leave this for you to show.)

Plugging this into the $g^{(2)}$-function you get:

$$
g^{(2)}(0) = 1+\frac{\langle N \rangle^2 + \langle N \rangle - \langle N \rangle}{\langle N \rangle^2} = 2.
$$